# Want to put additional items in my plot legend

Tags: plotting, legending

I was able to plot most of the parts of the figure. But I have a problem with some legend items. Here is my code:

```
θ = 0.30853753872598694`;
c[x_] := CDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], x];
cc[x_] := InverseCDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], x];
c1[x_] := (θ/(1 - θ))*(1 - x)
c2[x_] := (-x + θ + x θ)/θ
c3[x_] := 2*θ - x
c4[x_] := θ*DiracDelta[θ - x]
d[x_] := c[cc[1 - x] - 1];

p1 = 
  Plot[{d[x], c1[x], c2[x], c3[x]}, {x, 0, 1}, 
   GridLines -> Automatic, 
   GridLinesStyle -> LightGray, 
   PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
   PlotLegends -> 
     Placed[
       LineLegend[{
         Style[Subscript[P, M], FontSize -> 21], 
         Style[Subscript[l, 1], FontSize -> 21], 
         Style[Subscript[l, 2], FontSize -> 21], 
         Style[Subscript[l, 3], FontSize -> 21]}, 
         LegendFunction -> (Framed[#, RoundingRadius -> 2, FrameStyle -> LightGray] &), 
         BaseStyle -> 18], 
       {Right, Top}], 
   Filling -> {2 -> {3}}, 
   FillingStyle -> LightOrange, 
   PlotStyle -> {Blue, Directive[Dashed, Black], Directive[Dashed, Black], Red}, 
   PlotRange -> {0, 1}, 
   AxesLabel -> 
     {Style[Subscript[P, F], FontSize -> 21], Style[Subscript[P, M], FontSize -> 21]}, 
   BaseStyle -> 18, 
   AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[0.03], 
   AspectRatio -> .7];

Show[p1, Graphics[{PointSize[0.02], Black, Point[{θ, θ}]}]]
```

What I couldn't do:

1. The intersection of the butterfly area and the area below the red line should be dotted on the light orange color. Namely the area below the red line and the intersection of this area with the butterfly area needs to be dotted and on light orange.
2. I want to put the butterfly area as $\mathcal{B}_{\theta}$ into the legend. Like a square area dvided into two equal areas with light orange and dotted light orange
3. I want to put $\mathcal{S}_{\theta}$, which is just the dotted area into the legend as well. A square area with dotted lightorange.
4. I want to put the black point in the figure into the legend as $(\theta,\theta)$

I dont know how to do these things, although I spent time on it, and therefore I need help.

[image]

The final version:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by 'dotted and on light orange'? Do you mean the indicated area should be colored with light orange dots?

Comment: Suggest you don't use `Show`. Rather, add your black point using the option `Epilog -> {PointSize[0.02], Black, Point[{θ, θ}]}`.

Comment: @m_goldberg no just say black dots on the orange region. I tried to rule out the possibility of only a dotted region without orange backgound with the explanation in the question.

Comment: @m_goldberg thank you very much for the suggestion. I also wanted not to make two graphy and my idea was to just plot a single point giving its coordinates in the original plot. This didnt work out, because I couldnt scale it up or put a suitable mark-> this is usually what I was doing in Matlab. I used previously epilog but to add another figure, now I got the point, with epilog, live long epilog))

Comment: Re 1: Do you mean `Graphics[{Texture[
   Graphics[Disk[], Background -> LightOrange, 
    PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.25]]], 
  Polygon[{{0.5, 0}, {2 \[Theta], 0}, {0, 2 \[Theta]}, {0, 
     0.5}, {\[Theta], \[Theta]}}, 
   VertexTextureCoordinates -> 
    50 {{0.5, 0}, {2 \[Theta], 0}, {0, 2 \[Theta]}, {0, 
       0.5}, {\[Theta], \[Theta]}}]}]`?

Comment: Almost. The polygons seem ugly.very little dots, like in the salt and pepper noise http://de.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/remove-salt-and-pepper-noise-from-images.html

Comment: Maybe `Texture[ImageMultiply[Graphics[{}, Background -> LightOrange], ImageEffect[Graphics[], {"SaltPepperNoise", 0.1}]]]`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, a function to produce dots to be used as filling:

```
dotsF[n_: {50, 50}, sz_: Medium, clr_: LightGray] := 
 With[{g = Tuples[{Range[n[[1]]], Range[n[[2]]]}]}, Graphics[{clr, PointSize[sz], Point@g},
   ImagePadding -> 0, PlotRangeClipping -> False, PlotRangePadding -> 0, AspectRatio -> 1]]
dotsF[{10, 10}, .1, Green]
```

[image]

It will be more convenient to render the pieces separately so that we can generate legend icons for various components:

```
pltc3 = Plot[c3[u], {u, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, Opacity[1], Red], Axes -> False, 
   Frame -> False, AspectRatio -> 1];
pltd = Plot[d[u], {u, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, Opacity[1], Blue], Axes -> False, 
   Frame -> False, AspectRatio -> 1];
pltc1c2 = Plot[{c1[u], c2[u]}, {u, 0, 1}, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, Dashed, Black], Mesh -> {{\[Theta]}},
    MeshStyle -> PointSize[.03], Axes -> False, Frame -> False, AspectRatio -> 1];
```

**`ParametricPlot` with dotted filling:**

```
prmplt = ParametricPlot[{{u, (1 - v) Min[c1[u], c2[u]] + v c3[u]}, 
         {u, (1 - v) Max[c1[u], c2[u]] + v c3[u]}}, {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}, 
   Mesh -> None, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}},
   AspectRatio -> 1, BoundaryStyle -> Opacity[0], Axes -> False, 
   Frame -> False, AspectRatio -> (ar = .7),
   PlotStyle -> {Directive[{Opacity[.7], 
    Texture[ImageMultiply[dotsF[{120, 120}, Tiny, Red], Orange]]}], 
     Directive[Opacity[.7], Orange]}, 
   TextureCoordinateFunction -> ({#, ar #2} &), 
   TextureCoordinateScaling -> False];

show = Show[prmplt, pltd, pltc3, pltc1c2, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, 
 Axes -> True, Frame -> False, BaseStyle -> 18, AspectRatio -> .7, 
 AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[0.03`], GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> GrayLevel[0.85`], 
 AxesLabel -> {Style[Subscript[P, F], 21], Style[Subscript[P, M], 21]}, ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

**Legend icons and labels:**

```
labels = Style[#, 20, Bold] & /@ {Subscript["P", "M"], Subscript["\[ScriptL]", "3"], 
    Subscript["\[ScriptCapitalB]", "\[Theta]"], 
    Subscript["\[ScriptCapitalS]", "\[Theta]"], 
    Subscript["\[ScriptL]", "1|2"], "{\[Theta],\[Theta]}"};

icons = {pltd /. Thickness[_] :> Thickness[.05], pltc3 /. Thickness[_] :> Thickness[.05], 
   prmplt , ImageMultiply[dotsF[{7, 7}, .075, Orange], Orange], 
   pltc1c2 /. {Thickness[_] :> Thickness[.02], 
               Dashing[_] :> Dashing[.1], PointSize[_] :> PointSize[0]}, 
   pltc1c2 /. {Thickness[_] :> Thickness[.01], PointSize[_] :> PointSize[.2]}};

legends = Labeled[#, #2, Right] & @@@ Transpose[{Thumbnail[#, 32] & /@ icons, labels}];
```

[image]

**All together:**

```
Legended[show, Placed[Panel@Column[legends, Spacings -> 1], {0.85, 0.6}]]
```

[image]

**Update:** New requirements from the comments:

> I want to add this : LegendFunction -> (Framed[#, RoundingRadius -> 2, FrameStyle -> LightGray] &)
>
> ... make the box roundings a bit different and the legend transparent? so that the figure (and gridlines) staying at the background can be seen from the legend

```
prmplt2 = ParametricPlot[{{u, (1 - v) Min[c1[u], c2[u]] +  v c3[u]}, 
   {u, (1 - v) Max[c1[u], c2[u]] + v c3[u]}}, {u, 0,  1}, {v, 0, 1},
   Mesh -> None, 
   PlotRange -> {{0.2, c2[.2]}, {.2, c2[.2]}}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
   BoundaryStyle -> Opacity[0], Axes -> False, Frame -> False, 
   AspectRatio -> (ar = .7), 
   PlotStyle -> {Directive[{Opacity[.7], 
       Texture[ImageMultiply[dotsF[{40, 40}, Medium, Darker@Red], 
         Orange]]}], Directive[Opacity[.7], Orange]}, 
   TextureCoordinateFunction -> ({#, ar #2} &), 
   TextureCoordinateScaling -> False, PlotPoints -> 100];

icons = {Show[pltd, Background -> Transparent] /. 
    Thickness[_] :> Thickness[.05], 
   Show[pltc3, Background -> Transparent] /. 
    Thickness[_] :> Thickness[.05], 
   Show[prmplt2, Background -> Transparent], 
   ImageMultiply[dotsF[{7, 7}, .075, Orange], Orange], 
   Show[pltc1c2, 
     Background -> Transparent] /. {Thickness[_] :> Thickness[.02], 
     Dashing[_] :> Dashing[.1], PointSize[_] :> PointSize[0]}, 
   Show[pltc1c2, 
     Background -> Transparent] /. {Thickness[_] :> Thickness[.01], 
     PointSize[_] :> PointSize[.2]}};

legends = 
 Labeled[#, #2, Right] & @@@ 
  Transpose[{Thumbnail[#, 32] & /@ icons, labels}];

Legended[show, 
 Placed[Framed[Column[legends, Spacings -> .75], RoundingRadius -> 2, 
   FrameStyle -> LightGray], {0.85, 0.6}]]
```

[image]

> ... if one could make (one of the icons) a bit bigger:

```
legends2 = Labeled[#, #2, Right] & @@@ 
   Transpose[{ReplacePart[Show[#, ImageSize -> 30] & /@ icons, {3} -> 
       Show[icons[[3]], ImageSize -> 50]], labels}];
Legended[show, 
 Placed[Framed[Column[legends2, Spacings -> .75], RoundingRadius -> 2,
    FrameStyle -> LightGray], {0.85, 0.6}]]
```

[image]

Comment: This is something much better than I could expect. Some issues are about the beauty but I can definitely adjust them. Thank you very much for the answer. I will let you know.

Comment: Finally I am back to this question. I think I have done almost all. There is one little point. $\mathcal{B}_{\theta}$. It is just iconized version of the parametric plot and I was wondering if one could make it a bit bigger. Like via zooming and moving to the origin?

Comment: One more point, where I failed: I cannot manipulate the legend. I want to add this : LegendFunction -> (Framed[#, RoundingRadius -> 2, 
     FrameStyle -> LightGray] &)]   but how? I tried many possibilities and all was wrong. In other words, is there a way to make the box roundings a bit different and the legend transparant? so that the figure (and gridlines) staying at the background can be seen from the legend?

Comment: @Seyhmus, hope the update answers the new questions in the comments.

Comment: thank you very much. I tried them, so both have little problems and I rolled back to the previous version, which is quite okay. They are not so important I guess. Have  a look at the final version, I am putting to the question for a while.

Comment: @kguler thank you for this beautiful answer +1 :)

Comment: @ubpdqn, thank you for the kind words.

Answer (score 6):

I post for illustrative purposes only. I also suggest looking at [`LegendFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LegendFunction.html) documentation.

```
rp = RegionPlot[0 < y < Exp[-x^2] && x > 1, {x, -2, 2}, {y, 0, 1}, 
   BoundaryStyle -> None, PlotStyle -> LightBlue, PlotPoints -> 40];
p = Plot[Exp[-x^2], {x, -2, 2}, Epilog -> Point[{1, Exp[-1]}]];
Legended[Show[p, rp], 
 Placed[Column[{LineLegend[{Blue}, {e^-z^2}], 
    SwatchLegend[{LightBlue}, {HoldForm[\!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(1\), \(\[Infinity]\)]\(
\*SuperscriptBox[\(e\), \(-
\*SuperscriptBox[\(z\), \(2\)]\)] \[DifferentialD]z\)\)]}], 
    PointLegend[{Black}, \
{"(1,\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\[ExponentialE]\), \(-1\)]\))"}]}, 
   Frame -> True], {0.85, 0.7}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Here are some differences: For example how to fill a region of intersection of three curves? as is the case in the question. Is it not possible to use plotlegends?

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören The option `LegendMarkers` seems to allow you to use any expression in a legend, including arbitrary graphics.

Comment: @MichaelE2 how to select and fill the region on the intersection of three curves? the item 1 of the question.